# ipconfig /release /renew by Group Policy

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy, ipconfig

Doing some major network changes, would be nice to do some sort of bulk "release / renew" via Group Policy.

Is there a way to do this

Script perhaps?

Comment: If you know you are making changes ahead of time, why wouldn't you simply adjust your lease renewal times to be really short?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Zoredache mentioned in the comments, setting the lease duration to a shorter interval is probably the simplest method. That being said, you might be able to script something up that uses psexec against either a list of known machines or something generated out of a subnet scanner to run the commands. Test it on a few systems first :-)

Comment: Everything worked out great!